# When recycler veiw item is expanded (child views shown), the list should scroll to the bottom of expanded item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a custom adapter. Every item of the list contains hidden (collapsed) views, that are shown when I click "expand" button. The problem is if the item is at the bottom of the screen, item contents is left out of screen. Is it possible to scroll list view, so the contents of an expanded item be on the screen? I hope my question makes sense.

```
UnitCardAdapter.java
public class ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        cardBody = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cardBody);

        setListeners(unitCard, this);
    }
}

private void setListeners(final UnitCard unitCard, final ViewHolder holder) {
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    holder.unitExpandBtn.setOnClickListener( 
       unitCard.getUnitExpandOnClick()
}
```

```
UnitCard.java
public View.OnClickListener getUnitExpandOnClick() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!mIsExpanded) {
                expand();
            } else { 
                collapse(); 
            }
        }
    };
}

public void expand() {
    mIsExpanded = true;
    if (mViewHolder != null) {
        mViewHolder.cardBody.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void collapse() {
    mIsExpanded = false;
    if (mViewHolder != null) {
        mViewHolder.cardBody.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Recylerview is already rendered at that time so it will not scroll automatically scroll we can acheive it buy scrolling to that position manually by using this method.

```
reyleriew.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter).
```

but the problem is that it will do everytime so fo that we try to find out that is our clicked item is at last in screen to visible then we call above method so for that.

First / last visible child depends on the `LayoutManager`. If you are using `LinearLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager`, you can use

```
lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition()
```

And now for clicked item make to check

```
if(lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition == selectedPostion){
        reyleriew.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(selectedPostion).
}
```

I hope this works for You.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Maulik Togadiya! You gave me the brilliant idea. Yes I use `LinearLayoutManager`. I've tried to use `scrollToPosition(position)` at first place, but probably misused it, so it didn't work. But now it works. And actually I didn't have to use `findLastVisibleItemPosition()`, it worked well without it.

Comment: Okay thanks :) ,yes that is great.if have better idea and you can then please share your idea here so other people can know.